# JQuery conditions are executed for both state

Tags: javascript, jquery

Expected: Add additional class .long-ribbon to the span.ribbon.sports because the text are longer than 10 characters and it's after the .claimed ribbon.

Issue: Currently the issue is .long-ribbon classes are removed.

```html
<div class="block ribbons">
  <span class="ribbon claimed">CLAIMED</span>
  <span class="ribbon sports">XXXXXXX XXXXXXX</span>
  <span class="ribbon games">XX</span>
</div>

<div class="block ribbons">
  <span class="ribbon basketball">XXXX</span>
  <span class="ribbon soccer">XXXXXXX XXXXXXX</span>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".ribbons .ribbon").each(function () {
    var textLength = $(this).text().length;
    console.log(textLength);
    if ($(".ribbons span").is(".claimed") && textLength >= 10) {
      $(".ribbons > span.claimed").siblings().addClass("long-ribbon");
    } else {
      $(".ribbons > span.claimed").siblings().removeClass("long-ribbon");
    }
  });
});
```

I'm expecting that only the span with class sports that will be executed with .long-ribbon.

Comment: In your example, the last iteration will always `removeClass("long-ribbon")` from all siblings because only the first one in each div `is("claimed")`. Why don't you just select the claimed ones-- since it seems like those are the ones you're interested in-- and then check their text length instead of iterating over ALL of the spans?

Comment: *I'm expecting that only the span with class sports that will be executed with .long-ribbon.* `$(".ribbons > span.claimed").siblings()` will select *all* siblings of .claimed, so thats .sports and .games.  You likely need some context there such as `$(this).addClass` - "*it's after the .claimed*" - `.siblings()` goes forward *and* backward, it's not `.next()` or `.nextAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off looping through each `.ribbons` div and then using `find()` to see if any spans without the `.claimed` class have text longer than 10 chars, and that the `.claimed` class exists. Then add or remove classes accordingly:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".ribbons").each(function () {
    if($(this).find(".ribbon:not(.claimed)").text().length > 10 && $(this).find(".ribbon").hasClass("claimed")) {
      $(this).find(".ribbon:not(.claimed)").addClass("long-ribbon");
    } else {
      $(this).find(".ribbon:not(.claimed)").removeClass("long-ribbon");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.long-ribbon {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block ribbons">
  <span class="ribbon claimed">CLAIMED</span>
  <span class="ribbon sports">XXXXXXX XXXXXXX</span>
  <span class="ribbon games">XX</span>
</div>

<div class="block ribbons">
  <span class="ribbon basketball">XXXX</span>
  <span class="ribbon soccer">XXXXXXX XXXXXXX</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @symlink, but I'm wondering if the ribbons class are dynamic and can be changed with other classes.

Comment: @SW89 I see. I will upvote your question so it gets more visibility.

Comment: @SW89 See my edits. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sorry, I edited the description for better understanding, there's 2 conditionals that .long-ribbon only added to the text span that have a .claimed siblings and text length are equal or greater than 10.

Comment: @SW89 I think that my code satisfies those two conditions. See the updated code (I changed it several times so you might not have seen the latest one yet). The spans with the `.claimed` sibling are highlighted in blue. If I'm still wrong I apologize, I must just not understand.

Comment: thanks @symlink, it's really helpful and thanks for providing the solution for this, kudos to you :)